# pythonを用いてnxlogからAWS S3にログを転送したい。

Tags: python, amazon-s3

EC2（Windows）のログをnxlogで収集し、それをAWSのS3に転送したいと考えています。
以下の公式ドキュメントを参照し進めています。
https://docs.nxlog.co/addons/amazon-s3.html
しかし、IT初学者であるためよくわかっておらず、苦戦しています。

nxlog、pythonはインストール前提

1. Boto3をインストール
2. nxlog.confを編集
3. 転送用のロジックをpythonで書き、それをnxlogがアクセスできる場所に配置
4. nxlog起動

という流れと理解したのですが、3の手順が全くわかりません。
どんなコードを書けば良いのか、またそれをどこに配置すれば良いのか、分かっていません。

どなたか、ヒント程度でもご存知であればご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: nxlogを使用することが必須なのでしょうか？ 様々なツールがある中でnxlogを選択された理由もあげてください。

Comment: 結論から申しますとnxlogを使用したいです。理由は色々あるのですが、他のツールでの代替はこの課題においては視野にいれていません。あくまでもnxlogを使用して実現する方法を模索しています。

Answer (score 1):

公式ドキュメントに

> This add-on can be downloaded from the [nxlog-public/contrib](https://gitlab.com/nxlog-public/contrib/tree/master/amazon-s3) repository according the license and terms specified there.

とあるように、 `s3_write.py` は既に提供されていて、`BUCKET` と `SERVER` を指定するだけのようです。

Comment: ご助言ありがとうございます！なるほど、読み込みが足りておらず失礼いたしました。そちら確認いたします。